# XMLHttpRequest in javascript and basic functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I am making a website that receives a usernames highscore from a website that gives organized json data based on the username in the url. Below is the javascript code I have for getting the username from a input form after a button click and storing in a variable named RSname. The button click also executes the function getuserData(); The getuserdata method  takes the base url and concatenates  the variable RSname to the end of it. When I click on the button during a test I get an error saying this.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.tip.it/runescape/json/hiscore_user?old_stats=1&rsn=undefined.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:10315' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Why does it say that my variable RSname is undefined? Please help I am certain that I can figure this out I just need some guidelines or tracks to follow.

```
var errormsg = "There was an ERROR I am sorry";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#retrievestats').click(function() {
        var enteredname = document.getElementById('Userinputform').value.toLowerCase();
        var RSname = enteredname;
        getUserData();
    });
});

function getUserData( RSname ) {
    var requestURL = "https://www.tip.it/runescape/json/hiscore_user?old_stats=1&rsn=", 
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( "GET", requestURL + encodeURIComponent( RSname ) );
    // various sanitizations should be employed on the backend when dealing with user input
    request.responseType = "json";
    request.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    request.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
        if ( request.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( request.status == 200 ) {
                // process response
                var user_stats = request.response
                populateStatList();
            } else {
                alert(errormsg);
            }
        }
    }, false );
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is basically a rule stating that you cannot send GET/POST requests via AJAX/XHR to the domain or the file. Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: You don't pass any parameters to the `getUserData` function when you call it (`getUserData()`) try calling it like this `getUserData(RSname)`

Comment: @Titus was just about to say that! XD

Comment: *"Why does it say that my variable RSname is undefined?"* - Titus already explained this, but note that this just needed some very basic debugging. Where is the code that tries to set it? On that line, does the variable you are setting it to have a value? If not, where is that variable set? (Etc.)

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you guys for the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues: 1) Cross Allow Origin is going to be a major issue. It is up to the website administrators to fix this issue, not you. There is virtually nothing you can do except for bypassing the system, which won't be easy. 2) As @Titus said in the comments, you can't simply call a function and expect a variable to be passed. You have to insert the variable into the function.
Example:

```js
var myVariable = "Hi!";

function SlidinInYoDMs(myVariable){
  if(myVariable){
    //myVariable is inserted into the function. It is defined.
    var myElement = document.createElement('p');
    myElement.innerHTML = "This worked!";
    document.body.appendChild(myElement);
  }else{
  //myVariable is not inserted into the function. It isn't defined.
    var myElement = document.createElement('p');
    myElement.innerHTML = "This didn't work!";
    document.body.appendChild(myElement);
  
  }
}
SlidinInYoDMs(); //How you did it. Mind you, myVariable is already defined.
SlidinInYoDMs(myVariable); //How it's supposed to be done.
```

So in your `$(document).ready...`, instead of `getUserData()` it should be `getUserData(RSname);`


Side note: In the example above, `myVariable` is already defined. This is another way you could solve your little variable riddle.

```js
var myVariable = "Hi!";

    function SlidinInYoDMs(){
      if(myVariable){
        //myVariable is inserted into the function. It is defined.
        var myElement = document.createElement('p');
        myElement.innerHTML = "This worked!";
        myElement.innerHTML += "<br><br>myVariable = " + myVariable;
        document.body.appendChild(myElement);
        }
    }
    SlidinInYoDMs();
```

Comment: In order to bypass this would I need to do something like a reverse proxy? I was doing some further research on this cause it seems as this get request is the main idea around this whole project.

Comment: @Bluestreak22 Honestly, I don't even know how you could bypass this. I'd do a little more research, maybe there's some way you can get around this without even using AJAX.

Comment: @Bluestreak22 Remember, regular protocols work just fine when loading the URL. That's an HTTP protocol without any GET/POST request. Maybe there's some way you can request the file as if the client was simply loading it in.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable as parameter when you call getUserData() in your ready function, like this:

```
getUserData(RSname);
```

It's really basic in coding. In addition, why you transfer enteredname in RSname ? Useless

I hope it will help you.

Comment: request will fail CORS regardless

Comment: Ah I see this makes sense. I was getting an error before I transfered the enteredname. I couldn't find a solution until I tried that and it began working properly. Thank you.